# ¿Cómo eliminar kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 de un proyecto?

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Estoy en proceso de actualizar un proyecto de Laravel 6 a Laravel 10.

El el fichero `composer.json` del proyecto original se puede ver los siguiente:

```
"kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0"
```

Sin embargo, en el [github oficial del proeyecto](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2) se menciona que no tiene sentido utilizarlo a partir de Laravel 6 en adelante.

He procedido a no agregarlo al fichero composer.json del proyecto en Laravel 10, pero ¿Hay alguna guía o algo que cómo quitarlo completamente?

Answer (score 0):

No existe una guia oficial para quitarlo, pero en general si hay un metodo que yo sigo para limpiar este tipo de librerias:

- **Eliminar la dependencia del archivo `composer.json`:**
  Abre tu archivo composer.json y busca la línea que contiene la dependencia `kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2`. Debería verse algo así:

```
"require": {
    "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
    // otras dependencias
}
```

> ***Elimina la línea que contiene esa dependencia y guarda el archivo.***

- **Actualizar las dependencias:**
  Abre una terminal en la carpeta de tu proyecto y ejecuta el siguiente comando para actualizar las dependencias:

```
composer update
composer autoload dump
```

> ***Esto eliminará el paquete kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 de tu proyecto.***

- **Limpiar la caché:**
  Laravel utiliza una caché para mejorar el rendimiento. Después de hacer cambios, es recomendable limpiar la caché. Ejecuta el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

***Nota:*** También puedes ejecutar `php artisan config:clear` para borrar la caché de configuración.

Con esto deberias conseguir la eliminacion completa de la libreria en cuestion, ten en cuenta que si hay algun desarrollo que lo implemente tendras que migrarlo a lo que sugiera la documentacion de laravel de la version 6 hasta llegar a la version 10 que seria tu target.